# How are UTXOs handled in Ledger Live?

Tags: utxo, ledger-hardware-wallet

Take this Bitcoin transaction:

- https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/bad181b4bf50342e5226982ac5031d8b9ce670053d3b5c7502b0ff349a5f2838

In my Ledger Live, I can see that 0.3881168 BTC left the wallet:

[image: Ledger Live screen capture]

Which is weird, because I actually sent only 0.3878 BTC to 16fPHhrdaBuRNPH1YbEqC4fDE8tCUXNmuM, with the remainder 0.00065121 BTC being one of my newly created UTXO whose value was credited back to my wallet.

Why does Ledger Live not show the actual spent amount but instead the gross amount which is the sum of all used UTXOs? How can I only see the spent amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. I figured it out right after I posted the question.

Ledger Live shows the sum of the following:

- Actual spent amount
- The transaction fee

In my case, this is:

- 0.3878 BTC
- 0.00031680 BTC

Which is indeed equal to 0.3881168 BTC. I first got confused by this value because I subtracted 0.00065121 BTC (my newly created  UTXO) from 0.38876801 BTC (total input), but this is just a natural mathematical equivalence.